# how to commit or flush the rest response in the middle of process

Tags: java, jersey

I'm new to both java and jersey. Now I want to use the jersey to realize a REST services with extra processing after sending the response (specifically, sleep a fix amount of seconds and then fire a different REST request in the same servlet context, so it's unlike a REST proxy). I had googled for a while but all seems take it for granted that implicitly flushing the response at the end of method. Here are the current codes with JAXB enabled I'm struggling to work on.

```
@Path("/chat")
public class LoadSimulator {

    @Context private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Path("/outbound/{senderAddress}/requests")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response createOutboundSMSMessage(OutboundSMSMessageRequest inSmsReq, @PathParam("senderAddress") String senderAddress) throws JAXBException {
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(requestId).build();

        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        ResourceReference resourceReference = new ResourceReference();
        resourceReference.setResourceURL(uri.toString());
        JAXBElement<ResourceReference> inSmsResponse = factory.createResourceReference(resourceReference);
                return Response.created(uri).entity(inSmsResponse).build();
             //// want to flush or commit the response explicitly like:
              //        out.flush();
            //        out.close();
            //// Then sleep for a few second and fire a new REST request
            //        sleep(5);
            //          ....   
            // ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            // String response = r.path("translate").queryParams(params).get(String.class);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could do what you're trying to do, you would exhaust the resources on your server because every request would take X seconds and you have a finite amount of threads available before the box cries uncle.

Without commenting on *why* you'd want to do this; If you used the `@Singleton` annotation for your `LoadSimulator`  you could set up a thread that listens on a (concurrent) queue in `@PostConstruct public void init()` - that gets called when your servlet starts up.

```
@Singleton
@Path("/chat")
public class LoadSimulator {
    private Thread restCaller;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyInfo> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyInfo>();

    ...
    @PostConstruct public void init()
    {
        restCaller = new Thread(new MyRunnable(queue));
        restCaller.start();
    }
    ...
```

Then in your REST call, you'd put whatever information is needed to make the second REST call on that queue, and have the aforementioned thread pulling it off and making queries.

Comment: Brain, thanks for your sample codes. I'll study it to make sure I fully get your meaning since my java experience is very limited.